# Use $_SERVER in folder path

Tags: php

Currently I'm working on a script that checks a few domains for me. Now I wan't to know if a few folder paths are set correctly with this code:

```
 case "log_path":
 $obj->$key = $value === "/var/www/vhosts/'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/httpdocs/logs";
 break;
```

This is the path that should be checked:

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/logs
```

However the code that I posted above doesn't work. So my question, what is the correct way to implement a `$_SERVER` array in a folder path?

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT ROOT']  you can use this

Comment: try `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$obj->$key = $value === "/var/www/vhosts/{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/httpdocs/logs";
```

The problem is you are not ending the quote correctly. Your string is starting from `"` but to concatenate you are using `'`. instead of concatenating use `{}` to enclose `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` within string.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the document root key in the server array as in

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Do not forget to add a trailing slash after the document root

Answer (score 1):

Use: `$obj->key` object notation

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in concatenating string. Use:

```
$obj->$key = $value === "/var/www/vhosts/'".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."'/httpdocs/logs";
```

or

```
$obj->$key = $value === "/var/www/vhosts/{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/httpdocs/logs";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array items in double quoted strings like so

```
case "log_path":
$obj->$key = $value === "/var/www/vhosts/$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/httpdocs/logs";
break;
```